# Jxbrowser: how to replicate this code from v6, to acces dom and set inputs and clicks, to v7.15?

Tags: dom, jxbrowser

im trying to make a google maps clone (schoolproject) with my own searchbar in swing. I have been playing with the latest version of jxbrowser. And i am trying to access the "doc" to set inputs to the dom html using findById and setting with value with "value". I know how it is setup in v6:

```
    private void kButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_kButton2ActionPerformed
    DOMDocument doc = browser.getDocument();

    DOMElement address_element = doc.findElement(By.id("address"));
    DOMElement search_element = doc.findElement(By.id("submit"));
    DOMElement button = (DOMElement) search_element;

    DOMInputElement address = (DOMInputElement) address_element;
    address.setValue(searchbar.getText());

    button.click();
```

But how do i replicate this code in v7.15?
My Code in v7.15

```
//How do i do browser.getDocument(); ?

browser.mainFrame().ifPresent(frame ->
        frame.document().ifPresent(document -> {
            String baseUri = document.baseUri();
        }));
```

//how do i write this part, it cant resolve documentElement

```
documentElement.findElementById("address").ifPresent(element ->
                        ((InputElement) element).value(new address));

                documentElement.findElementById("sumbit").ifPresent(element ->
                        ((InputElement) element).click
```

/// how do i button.click?

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.mainFrame().flatMap(Frame::document).ifPresent(document -> {
                    String baseUri = document.baseUri();
                    System.out.println(searchLocationA.getText());
                    System.out.println(searchLocationB.getText());
                    document.findElementById("departure").ifPresent(element -> ((InputElement) element).value(searchLocationA.getText()));
                    document.findElementById("destination").ifPresent(element -> ((InputElement) element).value(searchLocationB.getText()));
                    document.findElementById("submit").ifPresent(Node::click);
                    System.out.println("buttons work");
            });
```

the solution